# unselectable edge showing only when smotted

Tags: edges

Iseed to have unselecteable edged that I can see only when in "Z" mode or Object mode but not in edited mode:

Edited mode - no edges:
[image: Edited mode - no edges]
Edited mode with "Z" - Unselectable edges
[image: Edited mode with "Z" - Unselectable edges]
Object mode, edges take shape
[image: Object mode, edges take shape]

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Is it possible for you to upload this part of model to something like [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably hidden this part in the edit mode, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> in edit mode to unhide the part of the mesh.